# react native status bar background color does not change on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, statusbar

```
import {NavigationContainer, useTheme} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {View, Text, StatusBar, useColorScheme} from 'react-native';

const Home = () => {
  const {colors} = useTheme();
  const theme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar
        backgroundColor={colors.background}
        barStyle={theme === 'dark' ? 'light-content' : 'default'}
      />
      <View>
        <Text>Hello World!</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I checked the status bar's background color changed to dark color on Android.

[image]

But the status bar background color does not change on IOS. Only text color changes on IOS.
[image]

Comment: try replacing `backgroundColor={colors.background}` with `backgroundColor="red"` and console.log `colors.background`